# cordova android permsision break after publish

Tags: cordova, permissions, google-play

I created a simple app with firebase notifications. When I run the app on my smarphone in debug mode, notifications work.

However, permission is not required when publishing on the play store. How to solve this problem?

Thank you

https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

Git of my app : https://github.com/lucaspojo/SteemDBM

Comment: push notifications don't ask for permissions

Comment: So why push notification doesnt work only on play store ?